# how to make embed in navigation controller work with scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, overlap

I have watched this tutorial 
[Snapchat Like Layout using View Controller Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHERMrAcmdo&t=235s)
then I embed one of the three controllers in Navigation Controller but it didn't work then i have tried to add it on the view controller how had the scroll view also didn't work + gives me overlap I didn't tried it in code tho but I don't think this is the cause , this is the code

[image: i hope this may help]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let V1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "V1") as UIViewController!
        self.addChildViewController(V1!)
        self.scrollView.addSubview((V1?.view)!)
        V1?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V1?.view.frame = scrollView.bounds

        let V2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "V2") as UIViewController!
        self.addChildViewController(V2!)
        self.scrollView.addSubview((V2?.view)!)
        V2?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V2?.view.frame = scrollView.bounds

        var V2Frame: CGRect = V2!.view.frame
        V2Frame.origin.x =  self.view.frame.width
        V2?.view.frame = V2Frame

        let V3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "V3") as UIViewController!
        self.addChildViewController(V3!)
        self.scrollView.addSubview((V3?.view)!)
        V3?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V3?.view.frame = scrollView.bounds

        var V3Frame: CGRect = V3!.view.frame
        V3Frame.origin.x = 2 * self.view.frame.width
        V3?.view.frame = V3Frame

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, height: self.view.frame.height)
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width * 1 , y: self.view.frame.height)

    }
```

how the code works ??
1- first I have added scroll view to a view controller 
2- then inside the scroll view I have added 3 view controller and all the 3 controllers has own class like normal view controllers
3- the scroll View added the 3 controllers on its view by this code on the top 
all the 3 controllers inheriting from own class and everything is wor fine 
if anyone can help or need more description just ask

Answer (score 0):

```
try below


Create ViewController in Storyboard or XIB and add ScrollView and PageControl

My Class as below:


class ScrollContentViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 4
        var originX = CGFloat(0)
        let width = scrollView.frame.size.width
        let height = scrollView.bounds.size.height
        for x in 0 ..< 4 {
            let V1 = UIViewController()
            self.scrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
            V1.view.frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
            V1.view.backgroundColor = x % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.lightGray : UIColor.darkGray
            self.addChildViewController(V1)
            originX += width
        }
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: originX, height: height)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let x = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        self.pageControl.currentPage = x
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: your method is works with the navigation controller but how I give every page or view controller a separate cocoa touch class  to work with it in storyBoard